# How to expand a related table in MS Access using the keyboard?

Tags: ms-access, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I expand the related table using the keyboard only?

[image: this one].

Do I have to click `+` using the mouse every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut is: Ctrl+Shift+DownArrow